# Facebook logout programmatically in Xamarin ios in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, facebook, visual-studio, xamarin

I have an application in IOS in which there is a Facebook Login Button.
when ever user clicks this Facebook login button My app redirects the user to the Facebook App installed in my device. So I want to logout the user from the application as soon as he leaves the facebook app and comes to my app.
i redirect the user to the facebook app using

```
NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromString("fb://profile/<id>");
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [Facebook login documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/). As the documentation described, I think you have added the `CFBundleURLTypes`, like this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb[APP_ID]</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
```

It means that Facebook will trigger the `openURL` to return back to your app via the URLScheme you have set here.

So, you can override `OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)` in `AppDelegate.cs`, and the parameters `url` or `options` contain the information related to Facebook. So, you can identify the resource.

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(url);
        Console.WriteLine(options);

        return true;
    }
```

According to this, you can do the action you want when return back from Facebook.

Comment: @Paresh, did my answer help you?

Comment: actually there is a bit problem with iPad So i cant test the code,
But will surely revert back once i fix iPad

Comment: @PareshSukhiya, if my answer is helpful, can you accept it? It's important to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Xamarin Facebook SDK? If yes you can do this to log out:

```
new LoginManager().LogOut();
```

Comment: It's not working with latest package version 9.0.1.5